# Error: conflicting types using C in Android ndk

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk

I am working on Android application in which I am using ndk to make my native C code in Java. My C and Java file code is given below, I am getting error on the compilation time for conflicting types.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "com_testing_ndk_FibLib.h"

// Implementation of native method sayHello() of HelloJNI class
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf('Hello World!\n');
   return;
}
```

FibLib.java

```
package com.testing.ndk;

public class FibLib {
       static {
          System.loadLibrary("com_testing_ndk_FibLib"); // Load native library at runtime
                                       // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
       }

       // Declare a native method sayHello() that receives nothing and returns void
       public static native String sayHello();

       // Test Driver
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          new FibLib().sayHello();  // invoke the native method
       }
    }



jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:6:24: error: conflicting types for 'Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello'
     JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
                            ^
    In file included from jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:3:0:
    jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.h:15:27: note: previous declaration of 'Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello' was here
     JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello
                               ^
    jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c: In function 'Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello':
    jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:7:11: warning: character constant too long for its type
        printf('Hello World!\n');
               ^
    jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:7:4: warning: passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer without a cast
        printf('Hello World!\n');
        ^
    In file included from jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:2:0:
    /Users/UsmanKhan/Desktop/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/include/stdio.h:247:6: note: expected 'const char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'int'
     int  printf(const char * __restrict, ...)
          ^
    jni/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.c:7:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
        printf('Hello World!\n');
        ^
    cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
    make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/com_testing_ndk_FibLib/com_testing_ndk_FibLib.o] Error 1
```

Comment: change __printf('Hello World!\n');__ to __printf("Hello World!\n");__

Comment: @Dayalrai thanks for your reply. Still i am getting the same error. Please help me out here.

Comment: please save the changes and clean your project before rebuilding, i believe you are getting same error due to old existing *.o files.

Comment: @Dayalrai i do it, but still nothing happens :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signatures for the methods are different:

```
public static native String sayHello(); // String return type here

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello(JNIEnv*env, jobject thisObj) // void return type here

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello // jstring (=Java String JNI) here
```

Try changing to

```
public static native void sayHello();
```

and in your header file as well:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_testing_ndk_FibLib_sayHello
```

(or all to `jstring` if you prefer that)